# java for fetching the one value

Tags: javascript

I need to get the emailid value from one json formated list the list is like i mentioned below

result:::[{name=sudersan san, emailid=divya.vairavel@gmail.com}, {name=Sasi Guru, emailid=ragavendran.kesavan@gmail.com }]

so please guys suggest me how can i get the emailid from above

i have tried the code in javascript for splitting.

```
if(data1.length >0 ){
    for (var k = 0; k < data1.length; k++) {
        var emailid= data1[k].emailid   
        var intname= data1[k].intname   
        var datevalue = localStorage.getItem("datevalue");
        var sessiontime = localStorage.getItem("sessiontime");

        $.ajax({
            url: "clientinteractoremail",   
            type:"POST",
            data : {
                emailid : emailid,
                datevalue : datevalue,
                sessiontime : sessiontime,
                intname : intname
            },          
            success: function(data1) { },
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: do you use java or js?

Comment: in java i need to split

Comment: Then why did you post a bunch of javascript?

Comment: Look up jackson or gson libraries for parsing JSON objects in java.

Comment: not working i need in java to get the emaild values in for loop

Answer (score -1):

```
var result = [
{
name="sudersan san",
emailid="divya.vairavel@gmail.com",
}, 
{
name="Sasi Guru", 
emailid="ragavendran.kesavan@gmail.com",
}]
```

Those statements pull the values from this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<result.length;i++){
console.log(result[i].name);
console.log(result[i].emailid);
}
```

you try this

Comment: How does this pull an email id from JSON?

Comment: @takendarkk: i wrote some code to pull name emaild. please have a look at it.

Comment: Yourr `var result = {` literal is invalid syntax.

Comment: @ torazaburo: i added var result = [{. please take a look at it.